# iMessage inside your App (iOS5)

Tags: ios5

I am developing an app for iOS 4 but now with iOS 5 I was wondering new possibilities.

Do you know if is possible to include iMessage inside the app (including a framework or something)? Or send a message to another phone via iMessage inside your app? Like the way we send mails inside ours apps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MessageUI framework added text in 4.2 if i remember correctly. I don't see why this wouldn't be using iMessage in 5.0.

You'll want to us `MFMessageComposeViewController` from the MessageUI.framework. You can find all the methods on this [page of apples developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668) however you'll need to be logged in with a registered developer account as it could contain pre release NDA stuffs.

It may not send iMessages instead of texts/sms' just yet (I say this as I haven't looked) but it should do in the future?

Hope this helps.

Comment: MMS is not supported using the MFMessageComposeViewController